# Regular Expression for name validation containing A-Z a-z 0-9 apostrophe ' and dash -

Tags: c#, regex, data-annotations

I'm trying to validate names that contains A-Z a-z 0-9 apostrophe ' dash - and space.

0-9 apostrophe ' dash - and space are optional, but it should not allow only these optional stuffs without any alphabet.

> ```
> For example, these should all match:
>
> Jean-Paul
> O'Donnel
> Jay-Z
> 2Pac
> Name with number in it like-> 50 Cent
> Name with hyphen and number-> Rob2 ben-den1
> ```

> ```
> Following should not match:
> -'2571 (only 0-9 apostrophe ' dash - and space)
> Empty String 
> 56757 (only number)
> ```

I've following Regex but it is not working for all above cases:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\'\-]+([\ A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\'\-]+)+$
```

Comment: Most probably something like `^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[ '-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$`

Comment: My advice: don't use Regex to validate names, there will always be someone who's name doesn't fit your standard. https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: this one is accepting only numbers also-
^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[ '-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$
not working properly @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: `^(?!(?:[ '-]*\d)+$)[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[ '-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$` - no only digits allowed.

Comment: I'm sorry @Wiktor but this is not accepting names like->  50 cent

Comment: No need to be sorry, [it is working](https://regex101.com/r/iMqKfB/2).

Comment: You must have an issue with the code, please update your question with it.

Comment: yes, thanks, It's working now @Wiktor. Post this as answer I'll accept and close the thread.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253263/discussion-between-logicaldesk-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?!(?:[ '-]?\d)+$)[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[ '-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iMqKfB/3).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!(?:[ '-]?\d)+$)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are one or more repetitions of an optional space/`'`/`-` and then a digit till end of string
- `[A-Za-z0-9]+` - one or more ASCII letters/digits
- `(?:[ '-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*` - zero or more repetitions of a space/`'`/`-` and one or more ASCII letters/digits
- `$` - end of string.